# C Function automatically concatenates char array arguments

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function, that deletes each character in s1, that matches any character in the string s2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[])
{
  int i1, i2, j, contains_char;

  for(i1 = j = 0; s1[i1] != '\0'; ++i1){
    contains_char = 0;
    for(i2 = 0; s2[i2] != '\0'; ++i2)
      contains_char += s1[i1] == s2[i2];
    if(!contains_char)
      s1[j++] = s1[i1];
  }
  s1[j] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
  char test[5] = "Test";
  char x[2] = "et";
  squeeze(test, x);
  printf("%s", test);
}
```

But when running the code it prints nothing. When i debugged it in gdb i found out that the variable s2 in squeeze contains the string "etTest".

Can someone tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: `char x[2] = "et";` does not have a null terminator, unlike `char test[5] = "Test";` Please try `char x[3] = "et";` or `char x[] = "et";`

Comment: Not sure if it is completely legal to change a string that is defined as you have - they are I believe constant and will cause issue.  You will need a work buffer.

Comment: ...in function `squeeze` the loop condition `s2[i2] != '\0';` is specifically looking for the missing null terminator.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan it is legal, they are just arrays, not `const`.

Comment: Tip: Instead of specifying the array size just leave it empty, i.e. `char x[2] = "et";` --> `char x[] = "et";` then the compiler will make the size correct.

Comment: @WeatherVane Strictly speaking these initializers *are* string literals. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p3 *A character string literal is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in double-quotes, as in "xyz".*

Comment: @WeatherVane Sure `"Test";` in `char test[5] = "Test";` is not a _string literal_?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the initialiser is a string literal, but the array which is initialised is not: the comment above said the array is not modifiable, but it is.

Comment: @WeatherVane I deleted my comments, they are wrong (probably too influenced by the fact that I am normally writing C++, not C).

Comment: OT: `contains_char += s1[i1] == s2[i2];` --> `{if (s1[i1] == s2[i2]) {contains_char=1; break;}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable s2 is not containing "etTest". It`s just your 2 variable (s1 and s2), storing in one memory location in stack. (comments about s2[3] is right )